# SubQueries in android sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am working with sqlite for android. How can I perform a query first and then perform another query on the set returned by the first query?

Comment: This is a rather vague question.  Without knowing what the queries do, there is no general answer.

Comment: You need to add more details in your question and what did you try to do

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff is right. Your question is very vague. So here's a vague answer to your vague question.

```
SELECT <column1, column2, ...> from <TableName>
WHERE <columnN> IN 
(SELECT <columnN> FROM <TableName> WHERE <expression>);
```

Try being more specific if you need real help with your actual issues.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use a subquery like a table:

```
SELECT SomeColumn, [...]
FROM (SomeColumn, [...]
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE ...)
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

However, this is possible only if everything is queried at once.
If you already have the results returned to your Java code, you cannot do a query on those results.